# Form of total differential

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose for a triangular ABC we have by the cosine law
$$
1=1+r^2-2r\cos\alpha
$$
hence $\alpha=\cos^{-1}(r/2)$. Moreover, let $\Phi=\theta+\alpha$.

Then it is said that
$$
d\Phi=d\theta-\frac{dr}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}.
$$

I do not see where the $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{4-r^2}}$ comes from.

I would say that
$$
d\Phi=d\theta - \frac{dr}{2\cos^2(r/2)}.
$$

Maybe 
$$
2\cos^2(r/2)=\sqrt{4-r^2}?
$$

Here, we are in polar coordinates by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have confused two notations.

When you solved the original equation for $\alpha$ and wrote a formula involving $\cos^{-1}(r/2)$, the meaning of that notation was the arccosine; i.e. $\arccos(r/2)$

However, later, when you computed the derivative, you forgot what you meant by $\cos^{-1}(r/2)$ and interpreted it as something else entirely: as meaning $1 / \cos(r/2)$.

Since $\arccos(r/2)$ is not $1/\cos(r/2)$, making this switch gave the wrong result.

Comment: Thanks! That was very stupid...